# Setting Base Layer in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I know there is a setBaseLayer function in [OpenLayers 2](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.setBaseLayer). Is there a way I can accomplish that in OpenLayers 3?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no concept of a baselayer in OL3, you can have multiple layers, and you can set visibility on them. This might help, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73982/openlayers-3-layer-visibility

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There is likely to be another way of doing it.

Comment: You're right. Getting all the layers and just insert a layer at index 0 did the trick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the base layer by doing:

```
var layers = this.map.getLayers();
layers.insertAt(0, base_layer);
```

Comment: Well done. I haven't had time to wrap my head round OL3 yet, so good to see things like this being posted.

Comment: I'm not sure this worked but this doesn't really work for now.